# Parse JSON string on ASP.NET web service, and return JSON string

Tags: asp.net, iphone, json, service

Hy

I'm an iPhone developer, and I have an application, which have to communicate with asp.net and mssql database behind that. I thought, communicating with JSON string would be fine. I've implemented the iPhone side, but after that, I've stuck. 
-How can I parse the JSON string into a .NET class?
-How can I call stored procedure with the data?
-How can I respond to the iPhone in JSON string?

Here is my implementation:

```
    MutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"**POST**"];
    [request setCachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageNotAllowed];
    [request setTimeoutInterval:60.0f];
    SBJsonWriter *writer = [SBJsonWriter new];
    NSString *paramStr = [writer stringWithObject:_parameters];
    [writer release];
    NSData *requestData = [paramStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

    [request setHTTPBody:requestData];
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [requestData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

Here is the log with the request and the payload (requestData):

```
URL: http://mydomain.hu/MainHandle.ashx/login

paramString: {"password":"myPassword","email":"myAddress"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like using an ASP.NET web service (.asmx file) that is decorated with the ScriptService attribute (System.Web.Script.Services namespace).  This will automatically convert an incoming JSON object into a .NET class and the result will be converted into JSON:

```
public class UserInfo
{
   public string password { get; set; }
   public string email { get; set; }
}

public class ServiceResult
{
   // Service result
}

[ScriptService]
public class MyService
{
   [WebMethod, ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false)]
   public ServiceResult DoStuff(UserInfo userInfo)
   {
      // Do stuff with userInfo.password, userInfo.email
      return new ServiceResult();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Deserialize<T>` method of the [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) class to parse JSON to a .NET class(.NET 3.5 SP1 and 4.0).
Call stored procedures by passing the properties of the class to the procedure as parameters.

Use the `Serialize` method of the [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) class to convert your .NET objects to JSON.

Or use a WCF service which will handle some of the serialization for you.

Comment: I would pay hard cash to see a *simple* C# webservice  communicate's with Android's App Inventor TinyWebDB GetValue and StoreValue methods. What I'm not clear on is if my Value Tags need to be defined (hard coded) in the service's code or if they can be be sent in the arguments to the web Service.